# An hard drive that is not always detected - and 912 bad sectors. Replace?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, bad-sectors

I have an HDD on a Dell Inspiron 15-3521 computer.

When I try to boot windows 10 on that computer, there is only a blank screen with blinking cursor. I checked the S.M.A.R.T results, and it turns out that the HDD has 912 bad sectors.
I am putting here the results of the S.M.A.R.T results:
[image: smart result 1]
[image: smart result 2]

Besides, sometimes that hard drive is not detected by the computer (It says that no boot device found), and sometimes it boots to the blinking cursor problem.
(If it helps, "Disks" software that I ran from a live ubuntu disk didn't detect any filesystem in that drive).

Should I replace that drive? Or there is anything to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like it's dead or dying. What are the full SMART results? Please [edit] the question.

Comment: How do I provide the full results? Is there is any way to export them?

Comment: No idea. I don't know what smart program you are using ...

Comment: I am using "Disks" (In ubuntu). But never mind. I will find a way. Thank you.

Comment: Can ubuntu read NTFS? tbh, I'd balance the cost of a new drive against the time since your last full backup & the value of the data.

Comment: OK. I have added the S.M.A.R.T results.

Answer (score 0):

Already the number of pending sectors justifies the replacement of the drive.
Partition the new drive to one big partition, format the drive and run linux "f3" to put the drive under a continuous load in the same mount position where the broken drive is.
The idea of running f3 is to find out if connection problems may have caused your sector failures.